# Save line break in textarea with php?

Tags: javascript, php

How do I save line breaks in a textarea with php? Currently I have this **temporary** solution by using `exec` to execute a shell string to get the job done but if possible I want it to be all in php. Here's my temporary script, please tell me how should I edit it

```
<?php

include 'theme.php';
/* ceklogin(); */
css();
if ($_POST['wget-send']) {
    $formdir = $_POST['dir'];
    $formlink = $_POST['link'];
    $filelink = fopen('/root/wget/wget-download-link.txt', a);
    $filedir = fopen('/root/wget/wget-dir.txt', w);

    fwrite($filedir, $formdir);
    exec('echo "' . $formlink . '" >> /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt', $out);
    echo $out[2];
    exit();
}

if ($_POST['restart-download']) {

    exec('mv /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt.done /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt');
    exit();
}

echo "<form action=\"" . $PHP_SELF . "\" method=\"post\" id=\"WgetForm\">";
echo "Download directory:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/>    <br>";
echo '<br>Download link:';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"13\" cols=\"62\"></textarea><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="LinkAdded()" name="wget-send" value="Download" id="WgetID"/><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="DownloadRestarted()" name="restart-download" value="Restart latest download" id="RestartWget"/>';
echo "</form></div>";
echo <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">

function LinkAdded(){

        alert("Link has been sucessfully sent to wget, it'll be downloaded soon, check the wget log for the download progress");
}

function DownloadRestarted(){

        alert("Download restarted, check the wget log for the download progress");
}

</script>
 HTML;
 foot();
 echo '
 </div>
 </body>
 </div>
 </html>';
 ?>
```

If I use `nl2br` the output file will be like this

```
satu<br />
dua<br />
tiga<br />
empat<br />
lima
```

I don't want those `<br />` in there. Here's the script with `nl2br` in it:

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $formdir=$_POST['dir'];
        $formlink=$_POST['link'];
    $filelink = fopen('/root/wget/test.txt',a);
    $filedir = fopen('/root/wget/wget-dir.txt',w);

    $savelink = nl2br($formlink);
    fwrite($filedir, $formdir);
    fwrite($filelink, $savelink);

    }

if($_POST['restart-download'])
    {
    exec('mv /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt.done /root/wget/wget-download-link.txt');
    exit();
    }

echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\" id=\"WgetForm\">";
echo "Download directory:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link:';
echo ("<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"13\" cols=\"62\"></textarea><br>");
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="LinkAdded()" name="wget-send" value="Download" id="WgetID"/><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" onclick="DownloadRestarted()" name="restart-download" value="Restart latest download" id="RestartWget"/>';
echo "</form></div>";
echo <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">

function LinkAdded()
    {
            alert("Link has been sucessfully sent to wget, it'll be downloaded soon, check the wget log for the download progress");
    }
function DownloadRestarted()
    {
            alert("Download restarted, check the wget log for the download progress");
    }

</script>
HTML;
foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

**NOTE** I want the output of my file `test.txt` to be like this WITHOUT the `<br />` part

```
satu
dua
tiga
empat
lima
```

Comment: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: I don't get this question at all. Where did these two files come from? What do they do? Where are your documenting comments?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Line breaks already exist and are preserved in a text area.

Answer (score 0):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) when saving the textarea into a database or text file. Then you simply can echo it in the textarea:

```
<?php

// Input (can be saved in database or text file)

$toSave = nl2br($_POST["link"]);

// Output (from databse or text file)

echo "<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"13\" cols=\"62\">$output</textarea><br>";

?>
```

Comment: I understand, but you simply can't do that without adding `<br />` or something else. Can you try to use `nl2br` when you want to output that textarea from your text file, or is that the problem?

Comment: Try using nl2br, then `str_replace('<br />', '', $toSave)`

Comment: @SkyLavi I'm not exactly following OP's question. He wants each word to be on a new line, sans <br /> and sans \n?

Comment: Why would you invoke a function to generate `<br />` substrings, then another one to remove them?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit He doesn't want the `<br />` in his code.

Comment: Yes, very good point @LightnessRacesinOrbit . It looks like OP wants the affect of `nl2br` (i.e. the linebreaks) without the <br /> tag. I think that `nl2br` DOES generate a newline in addition to adding the <br /> tag, but if I'm wrong about that, then this doesn't apply.

Comment: @Andrew: I really don't see why everybody is going on about `nl2br` if the OP wants newlines. `nl2br` generates HTML tags, not newlines.

Comment: @Andrew I get this error if I use `str_replace('<br />', '', $toSave)` after `nl2br`
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$filelink' (T_VARIABLE) in /www/test.php on line 11`

Comment: @orlea You have a semicolon?

Comment: Guys, I want it to be saved along with the new lines but without the <br /> part, do you get it? I want the output file to be like this:
line1
line2
line3

Please take a look at my updated post again. Thank you

Comment: @orlea Have you defined `$filelink` as `$filelink = fopen('/root/wget/test.txt',a);` and is the directory from this file correct to use in `/www/test.php`?

Comment: @orlea Could you paste the entire file in a pastebin.com file so we can better diagnose the error?

Comment: @orlea There is no semicolon after this line: `$simpan = str_replace('<br />', '', $toSave)`

Comment: @Andrew oh god, how could I be so careless, thank you very much for all the help. It works perfectly!